# Custom alertview based on date selected in datepicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker

Just started learning Obj-C; excuse naive questions if any.

I am trying to create an application that shows a custom alertview based on the date selected in a datepicker.

This is the code i have right now that shows a hard-coded alertview when any date is selected and the button is tapped. How can i make the dependent on the date selected.

```
(#)import "APViewController.h"
@interface APViewController ()
@end

@implementation APViewController
@synthesize datePicker;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)specialButton:(id)sender {

//  NSDate *chosen = [datePicker date];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Woohoo !" message:@"Its your   50th Birthday" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];

}

@end
```

Comment: What do you mean "dependent on the date selected"? do you want that date to appear in the alert?

Comment: @rdelmar Based on which date is selected in the picker the alertview must give an alert.
It should say Happy Birthday Mom for August 10th (whatever time)
and Happy Birthday Dad if 2nd July was selected.

the alert is executed on press of a button.

Answer (score 0):

Use an NSDateFormatter to format the date of the date picker to how you want it, then display that in the alert:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"cccc, MMM d, hh:mm aa"];
NSString * dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Woohoo !" message:dateString delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
```

If you are trying to show the age of the user assuming they put the date picker to their birthday, use NSDateComponents to get the year of the date, as well as the current year.

```
NSDateComponents * currentDateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSDateComponents * pickedDateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:datePicker.date];

NSInteger diff = currentDateComponents.year - pickedDateComponents.year;

UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Woohoo !" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Its your %dth Birthday", diff] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks" otherButtonTitles:nil];

[alert show];
```

You'll have to make sure it's not always "th". It could be "st" or "nd" or "rd".

Answer (score 0):

You need a data structure, preferably a dictionary where the keys are dates, and the values are the strings you want to display in your alert. When a date is selected in the date picker, search for a key in the dictionary that matches that date, and assign the value of that key to the message in the alert view.

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Could you please help with some sample code.

How can i do this "When a date is selected in the date picker, search for a key in the dictionary that matches that date"

Comment: @aceprogramer, you will learn it better if you try to work it out your self first, and come back with specific questions if you can't get it to work. You can use the NSDictionary method allKeys to get an array of the keys, which you can loop through, and test for equivalence with the selected date. Give that a try.

Comment: i have been working on the same lines, but have not been able to attach a value to every date that is selected.
I did this, but confused how to connect the key to the date selected.


`- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    events = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Awesome", @"Great",@"Decent", @"Surviving", @"Bad", nil];
    
    dates = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    date_keys = [dates allKeys];
}

Comment: Even tried this way, but ofcourse it doesn't work.

- (IBAction)specialButton:(id)sender {
    NSDate *chosen = [datePicker date]
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMd"];
    NSString *weekday  = [formatter stringFromDate:chosen];
    NSString *bday = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat: @"Jul26"];
    if (weekday == bday) {
        UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"What day is that?"message:@"Dad's Birthday"delegate:nilcancelButtonTitle:@"Thanks"otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [myAlert show];
    }
}`

Comment: @aceprogramer, you shouldn't be doing anything with a formatter, you want to stick with NSDate objects as your keys. But where do you create your dictionary? In the code you show above, you alloc init a dictionary and then call allKeys on it in the next line -- the dictionary is empty at that point there are no keys. You need to construct the dictionary with setObject:forKey: (once for each pair), or dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys: where you can pass an array of objects and an array of keys.

Comment: I have inserted the the array of objects and keys into the Dictionary; But it gives me an error when i compare the [datepPicker date] to one of the keys which are NSDate objects inside of an array.